# Lost disk space after removing bootcamp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, imac, disk-utility

Apologies if this has been posted before, but none of the cases seem to match mine exactly and I don't want to mess anything up.

After removing my bootcamp partition I am missing about 250Gb from my disk that was previously allocated to the bootcamp partition.

I'm using a 2017 iMac with a 1TB Fusion drive.

Can anyone offer any help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following the instructions in the link below, but in my case I used:

sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 0

[Lost space after removing bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356658/lost-space-after-removing-bootcamp)