# I have 2tb disk I created a 1TB partition to install windows. Now I can't merge that partition with my disk and I can't even find it

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

Now I just want to identify that disk again and merge with my MacOS disk so I can use the full 2TB again.

That's my disk utility list :

```
 /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
 1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
 2:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s2
 3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
1:                APFS Volume MacOS - Data            7.4 GB     disk1s
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 25.1 MB    disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.4 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk1s4
5:                APFS Volume MacOS                   11.0 GB    disk1s5
```

Comment: have you looked at the disk with Disk Utilities?  Be sure to click on the disk and not individual partitions on the left.

Comment: I believe that this same type of question has been answered before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost space after removing bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356658/lost-space-after-removing-bootcamp)